# spaCy: How to implement a special lookbehind in the word tokenizer?

Tags: python, spacy

I'm working on a text corpus in which many individual tokens contain punctuations like `: - ) ( @`. For example, `TMI-Cu(OH)`. Therefore, I want to customize the tokenizer to avoid splitting on `: - ) ( @`, if they are tightly enclosed (no whitespace) by digits/letters.

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51022249/8366805), I learned that I can modify the `infix_finditer` to achieve this. However, the solution still split on `)`, if a `)` is not followed by a word/digit, as demonstrated in the example:

```
import re
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
from spacy.util import compile_prefix_regex, compile_infix_regex, compile_suffix_regex

def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
    infix_re = re.compile(r'''[.\,\?\:\;\...\‘\’\`\“\”\"\'~]''')
    prefix_re = compile_prefix_regex(nlp.Defaults.prefixes)
    suffix_re = compile_suffix_regex(nlp.Defaults.suffixes)

    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, prefix_search=prefix_re.search,
                                suffix_search=suffix_re.search,
                                infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer,
                                token_match=None)

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)

test_str0 = 'This is TMI-Cu(OH), and somethig else'
doc0 = nlp(test_str0)
[token.text for token in doc0]
```

The output is `['This', 'is', 'TMI-Cu(OH', ')', ',', 'and', 'somethig', 'else']`, where the individual token `TMI-Cu(OH)` is split into two tokens `['TMI-Cu(OH', ')']`.

Is it possible to implement a 'lookbehind' behavior in the tokenizer? Therefore, for a tuple ')' that is followed by a non-word/non-digit character, before splitting on it to generate a new token, look behind in the first place to see if there is a whitespace between the ')' and the paired '('. If there is no whitespace, then don't split.

Comment: Do you want to avoid splitting on `.`, `,`, `?`, `:`, `;`, `…`, `‘`, `’`, backtick, `“`, `”`, `"`, `'` and `~`? Anywhere? Or between letters/digits only? Does it mean `TMI-Cu(OH)2,` should be the single token in the output, and not `['TMI-Cu(OH)2', ',']`?

Comment: The tokenizer works with each whitespace-separated string separately, so you can only look behind within that context.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi! I want to avoid splitting when punctuations comes between letters/digits, so `TMI-Cu(OH)2,`  should be `['TMI-Cu(OH)2', ',']`. The problem is if there is no letters/digits right behind `)` (`TMI-Cu(OH),`), the result becomes `'[TMI-Cu(OH', ')', ',']`, while the expected one is `'[TMI-Cu(OH)', ',']`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `)` from the suffixes:

```py
import re
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
from spacy.util import compile_prefix_regex, compile_infix_regex, compile_suffix_regex

def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
    infix_re = re.compile(r'''(?:[^\w\s]|_)(?<![-:@()])''') # Matching all special chars with your exceptions
    suffixes = nlp.Defaults.suffixes
    suffixes.remove(r'\)')   # Removing the `\)` pattern from suffixes
    suffix_re = compile_suffix_regex(suffixes)
    prefix_re = compile_prefix_regex(nlp.Defaults.prefixes)

    return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, prefix_search=prefix_re.search,
                                suffix_search=suffix_re.search,
                                infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer,
                                token_match=None)

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)

test_str0 = 'This is TMI-Cu(OH), and somethig else'
doc0 = nlp(test_str0)
print([token.text for token in doc0])
```

Output:

```
['This', 'is', 'TMI-Cu(OH)', ',', 'and', 'somethig', 'else']
```

Note the `(?:[^\w\s]|_)(?<![-:@()])` regex I used for infix matching matches any special character other than whitespace and `-`, `:`, `@`, `(` and `)` chars.

Comment: Thank you! :) This solution works fine except for one problem: if the sentence is like `This is AAA (it is TMI-CuOH), 50 mn, and somethig else`, when the `)` is not an enclosing tuple for `OH`. Is it possible to make further adjustment to detect such tuples?

Comment: @meTchaikovsky I suspect it is possible if retokenization function is implemented, you need to perform a retrospective check across tokens. I will check once I am back home.